# jquery $getJSON array not show all

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have data json schedule flight , but the getJSON does not show all information. It's just returning null some data and all data show null is already existing.

code :

```
$ (document).ready (function(){

    $.getJSON("/common/v1/airport.json?code=bgw", function(data){

    $.each(data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data, function(){

$("ul").append("<li>"+this.flight.airport.origin.position.region.city+"</li>");

    });

    });

});
```

this short data json i have , data array is [25] i get only 5 and error is `TypeError: this.flight.airport.origin is null`

my data json link [link](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=b3306901c23a8d98062959cec85b9c9e)

Comment: Is that json complete?  There are only _two_ occurrences of the property origin in there.  You make mention os [25] and 5.  Do you expect the length of the array to be 25?

Comment: my data json his so long i post short of him

Comment: We need to see all the JSON if we are to help you. Take the full json and compress it via a tool like [this one](https://www.browserling.com/tools/json-minify), then post it. We can de-compress it by using the beautifier at the same site. Your small sample is 9000+ chars and compresses to ~2000.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat i put my json on link check out http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=b3306901c23a8d98062959cec85b9c9e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least one object with null origin. You can do a simple check before appending the info to the list:

```
$ (document).ready (function(){
    $.getJSON("/common/v1/airport.json?code=bgw", function(data){

    $.each(data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data, function(){

      if (this.flight.airport.origin) {
        $("ul").append("<li>"+this.flight.airport.origin.position.region.city+"</li>");
      }

    });

    });

});
```

Comment: his wokr :) , thnak you very much , i have to question , 1- can use like this step in anguarljs ? .

Comment: In Angular, you would use something like $http or $resource to fetch data from the API (instead of $.getJSON), but you would need to check if origin is null in the same way as above.

Comment: Glad to help :)